# MVC5 dropdown List selected Items

Tags: model-view-controller

I want to have a drop down list with 3 values (super user-admin-user)  this is the role

this is my Model:

```
 public class LogIn
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [Display(Name = " username")]
    public string userame { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = " password")]
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string role { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my view(create.cshtml):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>LogIn</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.userame, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.userame)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.userame)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.password, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.password)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.role, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.role)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.role)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

this is my LogInController:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MVCSports.Models;

namespace MVCSports.Controllers
{
public class LogInController : Controller
{
    private LogInDBContext db = new LogInDBContext();

    // GET: /LogIn/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var list = new List<SelectListItem>
                   {
                       new SelectListItem { Text = "Admin", Value = "1" },
                       new SelectListItem { Text = "User", Value = "2" },
                       new SelectListItem { Text = "Someone else", Value = "3" }
                   };
        ViewBag.Roles = list;
        return View(db.sports.ToList());
    }
 // GET: /LogIn/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: /LogIn/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="ID,userame,password,role")] LogIn login)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.sports.Add(login);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(login);
    }
```

this is the index.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCSports.Models.LogIn>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Log In", "Create")
</p>
```

The role is not supposed to be a text field it is supposed to be a drop down list of the three values above and the selected value will be saved in the database.how is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, when you're showing the Login page for the first time, some how you need to prepare the values for the dropdown, so in your ActionResult method (not the HttpPost!!) you would have:

```
var list = new List<SelectListItem>
                       {
                           new SelectListItem { Text = "Admin", Value = "1" },
                           new SelectListItem { Text = "User", Value = "2" },
                           new SelectListItem { Text = "Someone else", Value = "3" }
                       }; 
ViewBag.Roles = list;
```

And then in you View you will have:

```
 <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.role, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.role, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Roles)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.role)
    </div>
</div>
```

This code will show in the view the dropdown with options and user answer will be saved to role field in your model.

Comment: it says that there is no definition for a "DropDownFor".what am I supposed to do?

Comment: DropDownListFor - my mistake.

Comment: no overload for method DropDownListFor takes 1 argument.also the "@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.role, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Roles)" shows an error :doesn't cntain a definition for ValidationMessangerFor...

Comment: I don't know what is going on with me today. please review my code again: the second part, now it should be fine.

Comment: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'role'. this error occured after debug on the dropdownlistfor statement.what'sis going wrong please

Comment: What is the db.sports.ToList() ? why are u sending this to the login view ?

Comment: problem solved only add this to the view  
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.role, new SelectList(new[] { "super user", "admin", "user" }))
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.role)